# Windows 10 make text bigger problems with office apps

Tags: windows, display, scaling, high-dpi

If I go on Windows 10 to `Settings -> Display -> Make Text Bigger` and drag the slider to increase text to 110% my office apps appear with fuzzy text. I'm not scaling though, but just making the text bigger. I have a monitor of resolution 2560x1440 and I have also tried to override high dpi scaling behavior on `Compatibility` settings but nothing works. Windows 10 seems to be pretty bad with scaling, does anyone have some tips on this ? Here is a image of blurry text boxes (Normal,Bad,Good,Neutral) on Microsoft Excel. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I am using 110% on a 1920x1080 monitor and the type is crystal clear. Update your video driver and then run Clear Type  (Settings, search for Calibrate Display Color and Clear Type is at the end. See if all that works.

Comment: @John I think this is rather a Excel thing, but compatibility settings high-dpi scaling tweaking doesn't work for me in Excel, check it out the image I uploaded to the question please. P.S: I am writing you after trying cleartyping, my problem seems to be unsolvable :(

Comment: Your image text is clear here (native Windows 10, Chromium Edge, and Kali Linux, Firefox. Did you update the Video driver?  Can you try a different Monitor?

Comment: yes my graphics card drivers are updated regularly. I have the latest AMD GPU driver, I have a dual monitor PC. Do you see the (Normal,Bad,Good,Neutral) boxes ? It's blurry but "Format as Table" it's not , very weird.